# Looking for the Closed Form of a Two-Variable Geometric Sum

Tags: hypergeometric-function, geometric-series

Is there any closed form of the equation $$\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} \cdot b^i$$ for real values $a$ and $b$ and integer $n \ge 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n-i} \cdot b^i=\sum_{i=0}^n a^{n}(\frac{b}{a})^i=a^n\frac{(\frac{b}{a})^{n+1}-1}{\frac{b}{a}-1}=\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a} $$

Comment: Thanks for the derivation; my knowledge is now +1.

Comment: What am I missing now?  $$ a^n\frac{(\frac{b}{a})^n-1}{\frac{b}{a}-1}= \frac{a^n(\frac{b}{a})^n-a^n}{\frac{(b-a)}{a}}=\frac{(b^n-a^n)a}{b-a}\ne\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a} $$

Comment: Oh I forgot to add $1$ to $n$, see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course: for $a\ne b$, it's $$\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$$

Answer (score 2):

hint: Write it as $$a^n\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^i$$

Comment: This is backwards.  You meant $a^n({b/a})^i$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint!

Comment: I like the hint approach.